# C++: Get numbers between two string delimiters and values after extracting desired integer from string using stringstream

Tags: getline, stringstream

````
    ```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <sstream>
    #include <vector>
    #include <fstream>

    using namespace std;


    bool findCurrentNumber (int currentNumber, int foundNumber) 
    {
        if (currentNumber == foundNumber) 
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


    int main()
    {

        ifstream inputFile;
        inputFile.open("C:\\Projects\\data.txt");
        if (!inputFile) 
        {
            cerr << "Error reading file "; 
        }
        else 
        {
        int searchCurrentNumber;
        cout << "Please type in the number you are looking for: ";
        cin >> searchCurrentNumber;

        bool foundRelevantSection = false;
        string delimiter = "energy";
        size_t pos = 0;
        string token;
        string line;


        while (getline(inputFile, line)) 
        {
             while ((pos = line.find(delimiter)) != string::npos) 
             {
                    token = line.substr(0, pos);
                    //check the found token
                    //cout << token << endl;
                    line.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());
                    stringstream ss;     
                    //store the whole string into stringstream
                    ss << token; 
                    string temp; 
                    int found; 
                    while (!ss.eof()) 
                    { 
                    //extract the word by word from stream
                    ss >> temp; 
                    //Check the given word is integer or not
                    if (stringstream(temp) >> found) 
                    cout << "Number found: " << found << " " << endl;; 
                    //no space at the end of string
                    temp = ""; 
                    }
                    if (findCurrentNumber (searchCurrentNumber, found) == true)
                    {
                        while (getline (inputFile, line)) 
                        {
                        if (foundRelevantSection) 
                            {
                                //if no matches were found, the function returns "string::npos"
                                if(line.find("total") != string::npos) 
                                {
                                    //relevant section ends now
                                    foundRelevantSection = false;   
                                }
                                else    
                                {
                                cout << line << endl;
                                }
                            }
                            else 
                            {
                                if (line.find("point") != string::npos )
                                {
                                    foundRelevantSection = true;
                                }
                            }

                        }
                    }               
                    else 
                    {
                    cout << "The number is not equal on this line compared to what is typed in!" << endl;
                    }
              }                     
        } //closes the while-loop
    } //closes the if/else-statement

    inputFile.close();

        return 0;
    }
```
````

Hi all,

I would like to parse an input file having this format:

> ```
> point     152 # energy  # 0.5
> 152 152 152 152 152 152
> 152 152 152 152 152 152
> total  0.011  0.049  0.035 
>
> point     153 # energy  # 1.5
> 153 153 153 153 153 153
> 153 153 153 153 153 153
> total  0.015  0.050  0.040
> ```

The code accepts an user-supplied integer and compares it to the number extracted from e.g. the string "point     152 # energy". If the user enters the number "152", the code should give following numbers:

> ```
> output: 
> 152 152 152 152 152 152
> 152 152 152 152 152 152
> ```

Unfortunately, my code returns exactly the opposite if number 152 is entered or if number 153 is entered no values are returned.

Could anyone help me and tell me what I am doing wrong? I am grateful for any hint!

Thanks in advance!

Best wishes,

DaveS

Comment: use a debugger or add cout with debug info in your tests / loops...

Comment: I already tried debugging and adding cout in order to solve the problem but I was unsuccessfull :(.

Comment: see the 2nd version of my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix for 2nd bug added at the end.

You should work on getting better with a debugger, I found your problem with one:

```
while (!ss.eof()) 
    { 
    //extract the word by word from stream
    ss >> temp; 
    //Check the given word is integer or not
    if (stringstream(temp) >> found) 
         cout << "Number found: " << found << " " << endl;; 
    //no space at the end of string
    temp = ""; 
    }
```

doesn't stop on finding 152 in "point     152 # ", but goes on to process # which turns found into 0.

This code with a break fixes that part:

```
while (!ss.eof()) 
    { 
    //extract the word by word from stream
    ss >> temp; 
    //Check the given word is integer or not
    if (stringstream(temp) >> found) 
         {
         cout << "Number found: " << found << " " << endl;
         foundRelevantSection = true;
         break; /* exits the while now */
         }
    //no space at the end of string
    temp = ""; 
    }
```

or you could test found in the while, by first setting it to 0, and testing with `&& found == 0`

Then the part calling `findCurrentNumber (int currentNumber, int foundNumber)` is garbage (or a placeholder for something way more complex?) as `if (findCurrentNumber (searchCurrentNumber, found) == true)` is simply `if (searchCurrentNumber == found)` which is much easier to read!

I didn't check if there are more bugs farther down the code, but with the break you definitely get the correct value in found.

**part 2**

You **already** found "point", so you shouldn't look for it again!
I added foundRelevantSection in the code above, before break.
Change the next part to (no if relevant, no if point found):

```
while (getline (inputFile, line) && foundRelevantSection) 
    {
    //if no matches were found, the function returns "string::npos"
    if(line.find("total") != string::npos) 
        {
        //relevant section ends now
        foundRelevantSection = false;   
        }
    else    
        {
        cout << line << endl;
        }
    }
```

hoping it was the last bug...

Comment: Thanks for the hint @B. Go! I removed the bool-function and replaced it with your recommendations. Nevertheless, it does not solve my problem. The problem still remains. I am not sure how to read in the lines and extract the numbers (see examplary output) after hitting the right number on that line using a delimiter for instance...

Comment: If the numbers is what you're interested in, you can use RegExp class from the C++ standard library to get those numbers out

Comment: Thank you very much @B. Go! This helped me alot!

Answer (score 1):

I checked your code, although isn't straightforward but I was able to understand what you're trying to achieve at least. Anyways, here is my own contribution to your question. I hope it helps you or at least gives you a better view of the solution

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <regex>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    ifstream inputFile;

    inputFile.open("sample.dat");

    if (!inputFile)
    {
        cerr << "Error reading file ";
    }
    else
    {
        int searchCurrentNumber;
        bool foundRelevantSection = false;

        cout << "Please type in the number you are looking for: ";
        cin >> searchCurrentNumber;

        //while we are still having data to read
        std::string currentLine;
        while (std::getline(inputFile, currentLine))
        {
            //remove the top and bottom section of the log 
            if((currentLine.find("point") == string::npos) && (currentLine.find("total") == string::npos ))
            {
                //now all the numbers are in the middle then search for the number
                size_t pos = currentLine.find(std::to_string(searchCurrentNumber));
                if(pos!= string::npos){
                    //we found the number so we are in the section hopefully
                    string line;
                    while (std::getline(inputFile, line)) 
                        {
                        if (foundRelevantSection) 
                            {
                                //if no matches were found, the function returns "string::npos"
                                if(line.find("total") != string::npos) 
                                {
                                    //relevant section ends now
                                    foundRelevantSection = false;   
                                }
                                else    
                                {
                                cout << line << endl;
                                }
                            }
                            else 
                            {
                                if (line.find("point") != string::npos )
                                {
                                    foundRelevantSection = true;
                                }
                            }

                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you also @Dexter's. Both solutions, delivered by you as well as B. Go helped me to solve the issue!